# On the proof of the Debut theorem for stochastic processes

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, filtrations

I found [this proof](http://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/EMIS/journals/EJP-ECP/article/download/1535/1535-5222-1-PB.pdf) of the Debut theorem and it's an amazing resource that is both short and straightforward (for almost every part of course, since I have a problem with it), but I am struggling tremendously to understand the inequality I've circled below.  It appears to falsely use $\pi \left( \bigcap_i K_i \right) = \bigcap_i \pi (K_i)$.  This is true for the way they define the $L_n$, i.e. $\pi \left( \bigcap_i L_i \right) = \bigcap_i \pi (L_i)$, but that inequality just makes absolutely no sense to me since this does not apply to the $K_n$.

[image]

Comment: This blog have all of that under the projections theorems entries :  https://almostsuremath.com/stochastic-calculus/

Comment: @TheBridge the Debut theorem on George Lowther's blog is a much easier version and covers only the hitting time of sets of the form $[K, \infty)$ for RC processes. The version stated in this paper is for the hitting time of any Borel set for progressively measurable processes

Comment: theorem 8 here https://almostsuremath.com/2016/11/08/measurable-projection-and-the-debut-theorem/ is as general as a debut theorem can be though

Comment: And the proof of th9e measurable projection is nothing like trivial

Comment: If I remember the proof well it's all about choosing correctly the K_n and I would be surprised if the proof above was correct as the strategy to do so is incredibly astute (and based on a game)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the following is true $\pi(A\cap B)\subset \pi(A)\cap \pi(B)$ so as $\pi(\cap_{i=1}^n K_i)\subset \cap_{i=1}^n \pi(K_i)$ so

$ \cap_{i=1}^n \pi(K_i)^c\subset \pi(\cap_{i=1}^n K_i)^c$ and

$\pi(A_n) \cap \cap_{i=1}^n \pi(K_i)^c\subset \pi(A_n) \cap \pi(\cap_{i=1}^n K_i)^c$

But this is

$\cap_{i=1}^n\pi(A_n)\backslash \pi(K_i)\subset \pi(A_n) \backslash\pi(\cap_{i=1}^n K_i)$

So this cannot work because there is no specification in this proof as to how choose the $K_n$ so that
$\pi(A_n) \backslash\pi(\cap_{i=1}^n K_i)\subset \cap_{i=1}^n\pi(A_i)\backslash \pi(K_i)$

To do that is very hard and I let you look at the very readable but still hard to understand proof of measurable projection here where the point is to define a proper strategy to get the rights $K_n$ from a:
https://almostsuremath.com/2019/01/10/proof-of-the-measurable-projection-and-section-theorems/

Comment: Thank you! I was looking at the wrong blog post re: my original comment.  So we may still use the same strategy as in the paper I linked, but we just need to make sure we choose $K_n$ appropriately using the measurable projection proof from Lowther?  Or should I just ignore the paper at this point?  Everything else in it is correct as far as I can read apart from the way $K_n$ are chosen.

Comment: You should ignore the paper in my opinion or more specifically the the proof of the theorem you are mentioning as I don't see how you can show the necessary property to get the inequality right . My conjecture is that it is not possible to do so trivially as in the proof in GL's blog uses a very unintuitive way to select the right K_n (it uses some adversarial game) so that I don't think that the proof is right but maybe there is something I have missed.